# how to create relationship using cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have been learning neo4j/cypher for the last week. I have finally been able to upload two csv files and create a relationship,"captured". However, I am not fully confident in my understanding of the code as I was following the tutorial on the neo4j site. Could you please help me confirm what I did is correct.

I have two csv files, a "cap.csv" and a "survey.csv". The survey table contains data of each unique survey conducted at the survey sites. the cap table contains data of each unique organisms captured. In the cap table I have a foreign key, "survey_id", which in the Postgres db you would join to the p.key in the survey table.

I want to create a relationship, "captured", showing each unique organsism that was captured based on the "date" column in the survey table.

Survey table
| lake_id | date |survey_id | duration |
| -------- | -------------- | --| --
| 1    | 05/27/14            |1 | 7 |
| 2   | 03/28/13            | 2|10 |
| 2  | 06/29/19            | 3|23 |
| 3   | 08/21/21            | 4|54 |
| 1    | 07/23/18            | 5|23 |
| 2   | 07/22/23            | 6|12 |

Capture table
| cap_id | species |capture_life_stage | weight | survey_id |
| -------- | -------------- | --| -----|---|
| 1    | a            |adult | 10 | 1|
| 2   | a           | adult|10 | 2 |
| 3  | b           | juv|23 | 3 |
| 4   | a            | adult|54 | 4 |
| 5    | b            | juv|23 | 5 |
| 6   | c            | juv |12 | 6 |

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///cap.csv' AS row
WITH
row.id as id, 
row.species as species,
row.capture_life_stage as capture_life_stage,
toInteger(row.weight) as weight,
row.survey_id as survey_id
MATCH (c:cap {id: id})
MERGE (s) - [rel:captured {survey_id: survey_id}] ->(c)
return count(rel)
```

I am struggling to understand the code I wrote above. I followed the neo4j tutorial exactly but used my data (https://neo4j.com/developer/desktop-csv-import/).

1. I am fairly confident from data checks, but did the above code create the "captured" relationship showing each unique organism captured on that unique survey date? Based on the visual I can see I believe it did but I don't fully understand each step in the code.
2. What is the purpose of the `MATCH (c:cap {id: id})` in the code?

Answer (score 1):

The code below

```
 MATCH (c:cap {id: id})
```

is the same as

```
 MATCH (c:cap)
 Where c.id = id
```

It is a shorter way of finding Captured node based on id and then you are creating a relationship with Survey node.

Question: s is not defined in your query. Where is it?

Comment: "s" was the name of the survey table that I loaded before that query. So then the second half of ``` MATCH (c:cap {id: id})
MERGE (s) - [rel:captured {survey_id: survey_id}] ->(c)``` code creates the relationship for captured when survey_id = survey_id between the two tables? In human speak I can think of this whole chunk as, "give the nodes in the cap table for id, then create a relataionship on the survey table that is called "captured" when survey_id = survey_id for the cap table"?